# Dictionary key name from combination of string and variable value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I am trying to append values from a list as key-value pairs to a new dictionary. I want the key names in a specific format and order.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
ipv4_list = ["192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
ipv4_dic = {}
ipv4_len = len(ipv4_list)
i = 1

for val in range(len(ipv4_list)):
    ipv4_dic[i] = ipv4_list[val]
    i+=1

print(ipv4_dic)
```

Current output:

```
{1: '192.168.1.2', 2: '192.168.1.3', 3: '192.168.1.4'}
```

The above is good but I want to change key names to something like IP1, IP2, etc.

How do I make that in the line `ipv4_dic[i] = ipv4_list[key]`

I tried something like `ipv4_dic["IP"+i]` but does not work.

```
    ipv4_dic["IP"+i] = ipv4_list[val]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

The expected dictionary output as follows:

```
{IP1: '192.168.1.2', IP2: '192.168.1.3', IP3: '192.168.1.4'}
```

Comment: The reason why "*it does not work*" (please include the error next time) is that you can't add a string and a text value. The format string answer is a good one but you can also use `ipv4_dic["IP"+str(i)]`. I would personally use the answer by @john_geiogio

Comment: That's great. Yes, I edited the question and included the error also now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension with enumerate starting a 1:

```
ipv4_list = ["192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
ipv4_dic  = {f'IP{n}':ip for n,ip in enumerate(ipv4_list,1)}

print(ipv4_dic)
{'IP1': '192.168.1.2', 'IP2': '192.168.1.3', 'IP3': '192.168.1.4'}
```

Comment: humm, that's exactly what I wrote 2 hrs before.

Comment: I know, except for using the 2nd parameter of enumerate to start at 1 directly instead of adding one to the default numbering.

Comment: Fair enough, +1 for insight.

Answer (score 5):

It does not work because you are trying to concatenate a string with an integer, which is not allowed in Python.

In order to have your code working with the minimum possible amendments is to transform the integer `i` to a string, via the `str()` function, i.e. replacing in your code

```
ipv4_dic["IP"+i] = ipv4_list[val]
```

with

```
ipv4_dic["IP"+str(i)] = ipv4_list[val]
```

However, you can use dict comprehension, i.e. you loop each position of the `ipv4_dic` you're about to create, placing there a key built from each element of your `ipv4_list`, in a single line of code.

```
ipv4_list = ["192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
ipv4_dic = {f"IP{i+1}": ipv4_list[i] for i in range(len(ipv4_list))}
```

**Explanation**:
for each `i` in the range from `0` to `len(ipv4_list)` we are building the single dictionary key through an `f-string`, concatenating the string `"IP"` to the value `i+1` (the range starts at `0`, but you want your first dict element to be `"IP1"`, that's why `i+1`). Then, we set the value for this key as `ipv4_list[i]`, which are the single elements contained in your starting list.

The basic  usage is

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']

d = {i : l[i] for i in range(len(l))}
```

which is pretty similar to your case, without the refinements in the keys creation, since you're incrementing the index (i.e. `i`) and concatenating it to a string.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you described why the original attempt did not work and what "f-strings" are. SO is not keen on "code only" answers.

Comment: Nice. But would be really helpful for me and others if you describe/explain the solution/answer a bit more.

Comment: Good but check out [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)makes your solution more elegant.  Basically any time you want to track an index in a for loop:  enumerate…

Answer (score 1):

```py
ipv4_list = ["192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
ipv4_dict= {}

# enumerate will give you the index and value of the iterator
# f-string can compute the value inside the {} and format it like a string

for index,value in enumerate(ipv4_list):
    ipv4_dict[f"IP{index+1}"] = value
# or 
ipv4_dict_1 = {f"IP{index+1}": value for index,value in enumerate(ipv4_list)}

# out:
print(ipv4_dict)
# {'IP1': '192.168.1.2', 'IP2': '192.168.1.3', 'IP3': '192.168.1.4'}
print(ipv4_dict_1)
# {'IP1': '192.168.1.2', 'IP2': '192.168.1.3', 'IP3': '192.168.1.4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost didn’t post this because Georgio almost had what I would have written:  use a dictionary comprehension based on a for loop.  Andd tell you about the `str` and `int` concatenation.

The only thing missing was using enumerate to get the list indices.  Full of goodness, is enumerate. It returns the elements from an iterable as a list of pairs (tuples):  first item is the zero-based index, second is what the for loop (well actually the iterable at that index) would normally return.

Then those pairs get assigned to `i,v` via [tuple unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/).

```
di = { f"IP{i+1}":v for i,v in enumerate( [" 192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"])}
print(di)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries work like this:

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
```

Try this:

```
ipv4_list = ["192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
ipv4_dic = {}
ipv4_len = len(ipv4_list)
i = 1

for key in range(len(ipv4_list)):
    auxStr = "IP" + str(i)  #convert i to string, and merging IP
     ipv4_dic[auxStr] = ipv4_list[key]
    i+=1

print(ipv4_dic)
```

This should do it!
Happy coding!!!

Comment: Not good your result is: {1: {'IP1': '192.168.1.2'}, 2: {'IP2': '192.168.1.3'}, 3: {'IP3': '192.168.1.4'}}
Please modify your code to have me voting up

Comment: Change -->  ipv4_dic[i] = {auxStr: ipv4_list[key]} to --> ipv4_dic[auxStr] = ipv4_list[key]

Comment: Not good your result is: {1: {'IP1': '192.168.1.2'}, 2: {'IP2': '192.168.1.3'}, 3: {'IP3': '192.168.1.4'}} Please modify your code to have me voting up 

Change --> ipv4_dic[i] = {auxStr: ipv4_list[key]} to --> ipv4_dic[auxStr] = ipv4_list[key]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).